# Does the shield of an ADC go down faster?

Tags: league-of-legends

Does the shield of an ADC go down faster than the shield of a tank?

IE does armor/mr increase the defense of a shield?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shields are basically "Temporary Bonus Health". They do benefit from Armor and Magic resistance. Magic damage only shields will also benefit from Magic resistance but they don't absorb Physical damage (so maybe they do benefit from it technically but it's useless).

So yes, Shields on Squishy targets will go down faster. But note that squishy means no resistances in this context. A lot of health will not make your shield stronger, a lot of resistance will.